# Want to close instabug session in version 11.0.2 Is there any method for this?

Tags: javascript, react-native, instabug

In Instabug there is a start method for creating the session which accepts the token and invocation event array. But is there anyway to close instabug session like how we start it?

I found a method like enable but this method works only for android

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.